# How do I determine the constructor ABI for Etherscan contract verification?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, etherscan, constructor, rinkeby

I am facing issues trying to verify a contract that I deployed on Rinkeby.

My contract constructor has 3 parameters, how do I pass values of these parameters in the contract verification form?

How do I determine the constructor ABI for my contract. Btw, I am using compiler version 4.11 and the contract was built using truffle framework.

Any help would be truly appreciated.

Comment: What types were the parameters?

Comment: (address, uint, uint) => first is an address to which proceeds of the contract will be forwarded to, the second is the starting block number, the third is the ending block number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now it is very easy with [ABI-encoded Online Converter](https://abi.sonnguyen.ws)

Step 1: Add parameters that you used to construct your contract

Step 2: Click Generate ABI

Step 3: Copy ABI-Encoded

Step 4: Back to Etherscan and pasted it to ABI-Encoded Textbox

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For simple value types like `address` and `uint`, you just need to left-pad the values to 32 bytes and concatenate them.

For example, if my values were

- 0x829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a830
- 4
- 177772

the proper ABI encoding would be

```
000000000000000000000000829bd824b016326a401d083b33d092293333a8300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002b66c
```

For more complicated types or to do this automatically, you can use this [JS tool](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi)